# JS: How to filter an array of objects, add to the first object a key with values of the rest of filtered elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am trying to implement in Tabulator JS an opportunity for user to reconstruct from a table a new one with tree structure. So tableData is an assumed table and columnTree is user's choice which column has to be the tree root.

My idea is firstly to store unique key values in an array, then loop through the tableData filtering it by each key, add to the first element [_children] key with values of the rest of the filtered objects.

```
var columnTree = "continent";

var tableData = [
                {continent:"Asia", country:"China"},
                {continent:"Asia", country:"Vietnam"},
                {continent:"Asia", country:"Thai"},
                {continent:"America", country:"USA"},
                {continent:"America", country:"Canada"},
                {continent:"Africa", country:"Egypt"},
                {continent:"Africa", country:"Somalia"},
            ];
```

Get unique keys

```
var unique = tableDataNested.map(item => item[columnTree]).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);

// ["Asia", "America", "Afrika"]
```

Filter function

```
function filterByValue(array, string) {
                return array.filter(o =>
                    Object.keys(o).some(k => o[k].toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase())));
            };
```

The last step

```
var finalArray = [];
unique.forEach(function(continent) {
                //temporary array with values of each continent 
                var tempArray = filterByValue(tableDataNested, continent);
                console.log(tempArray);
                //get the first object
                console.log(tempArray[0]);
                //add to the first object '_children' key with values of the rest of objects except the 
                //first.
                var finalResult = tempArray[0]['_children'] = [tempArray.slice(1)];
                console.log(finalResult);
                finalArray.push(finalResult);
            });
```

The thing is, it crashes on the second continent and I can't get why

```
VM480:3 Uncaught TypeError: o[k].toLowerCase is not a function
    at <anonymous>:3:51
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:3:36
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at filterByValue (<anonymous>:2:30)
    at <anonymous>:2:33
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:8
```

My ideal result is

```
var finalArray = [
                {continent:"Asia", country:"China", "_children": [
                    {continent:"Asia", country:"Vietnam"},
                    {continent:"Asia", country:"Thai"}
                ]},
                {continent:"America", country:"USA", "_children": [
                    {continent:"America", country:"Canada"},
                ]},
                {continent:"Africa", country:"Egypt",  "_children": [
                    {continent:"Africa", country:"Somalia"}
                ]}
            ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off using a generic `groupBy` function, for example

```
function groupBy(ary, fn) {
    let m = new Map();
    for (let x of ary) {
        let key = fn(x);
        if (!m.has(key))
            m.set(key, []);
        m.get(key).push(x);
    }
    return m;
}
```

and then

```
let groupMap = groupBy(tableData, x => x[columnTree]);
let result = [];

for (let [first, ...rest] of groupMap.values()) {
    first._children = rest;
    result.push(first);
}
```

Note that this also mutates the original `tableData` array, if this is not desirable, change the loop body to:

```
result.push({...first, _children: rest});
```

Answer (score 1):

## The simpler way is using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to aggregate your data.

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on
> each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

```js
var tableData = 
[
  {continent:"Asia", country:"China"},
  {continent:"Asia", country:"Vietnam"},
  {continent:"Asia", country:"Thai"},
  {continent:"America", country:"USA"},
  {continent:"America", country:"Canada"},
  {continent:"Africa", country:"Egypt"},
  {continent:"Africa", country:"Somalia"},
];

var result = tableData.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(acc[item.continent] === undefined)
     acc[item.continent] = { continent: item.continent, country: item.country, _children: []}
  else
    acc[item.continent]._children.push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```